# weight deduction simplify the code if possible

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to deduct weight of 2kg from every 40kg. If I have 200Kg then the deduction will be 10kg and so on... Problem is I have used IF for every 40kg see the coding. Please help me to simplify this code as short as possible.

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
            String s = edW.getText().toString();
            Float w= Float.parseFloat(s);
            Float weight = w*40;
            if (weight <= 20){
                Float oneKG = weight - 1;
                txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ oneKG);
            }
             if (weight>20 && weight <=40){
                Float twoKG = weight - 2;
                txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ twoKG);
            }

            if (weight>40 && weight <=80){
                Float fourKG = weight - 4;
                txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ fourKG);
            }
             if (weight>80 && weight <=120){
                Float sixKG = weight - 6;
                txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ sixKG);
            }
             if (weight>120 && weight <=160){
                Float eightKG = weight - 8;
                txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ eightKG);
            }
             if (weight>160 && weight <=200){
                Float tenKG = weight - 10;
                txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ tenKG);
            }
            else {
                txtV.setText("Else Running");
            }


        }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSRQD.jpg)

Comment: Why did you use kotlin as a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, should solve your issue

```
class Value{
    public int wholeNumber;
    public int decimalNumber;
}

private Value getWholeDecimalNumber(String s) {
    String[] arr = String.valueOf(s).split("\\.");
    Value value = new Value();
    value.wholeNumber = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        value.decimalNumber = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
    }
    return value;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    String s = edW.getText().toString();
    Value value = getWholeDecimalNumber(s);
    int w= value.wholeNumber;
    int weight = w*40 + value.decimalNumber;
    int weightToDeduct = w*2;

    if (value.decimalNumber > 0) {
        if (value.decimalNumber > 20) {
            weightToDeduct += 2;
        }
        else {
            weightToDeduct += 1;
        }
   }
   txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ (weight - weightToDeduct));
```

}

Ex - 
a) for 1 as input , weight = 1x40 = 40, weightToDeduct = 1x2 = 2, total kg = (weight - weightToDeduct) = 40-2 = 38kg

b) for 5 as input , weight = 5x40 = 200, weightToDeduct = 5x2 = 10, total kg = (weight - weightToDeduct) = 200-10 = 190kg

Comment: Again One problem is facing when weight is in friction eg: 1.36, 
Here 1 equal to 40kg plus 36kg now deduction will be 4kg. 2kg from 40kg and 2kg from 36kg now total weight is 1.32 net weight.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question in detail for the fraction case, how much deduction gonna happen ? do we need to consider fraction value in kgs and if that is less than 40 kg we have to deduct 2 kg ? for example 1.23 [1 = 40kg, .23 = 23kg] deduction values are [2 for 40kg and 2 for 23 kg ]

Comment: Yes. When weight < 20kg then deduct 1kg, when weight > 20kg deduction will 2kg.
In case of mounds every mound equal to 40kg so we deduct 2kg from each.

Comment: your views accept input in form of 1.60 ? if yes then should we need to consider 2.20 ?

Comment: No. I have two editText fields one is for mounds and other one is for KG eg. [2].[20], in second textEdit I will set the condition that will not accept the greater then 40 value

Comment: Just verified by myself as well, working as expected, accordingly have modified the code, please use the latest answer code and use the same. If this works for you please accept the answer and vote up.

Comment: There I left some typo mistake, now corrected the code, please use the latest.

Comment: @ShafiqueRehman did the solution work ? please do let me know

Comment: Can I remove second textEdit field?
This solution can work with only one edit field?

Comment: Yes, that can be done. But we need to change the code accordingly. Can you please accept the answer as it works for you, also do vote up... so no one can put the same effort for the same issue.

Comment: Working but result is not correct. I entered 2.19 result was returned 75kg instead of 94. It means deduction is correct but 19 not added.

Comment: output 75 is correct for 2.19, 2 = 80 and deduction will be 4, and for .19 should be 1, total deduction is 5. now 80-5 = 75

Comment: And what about 19kg where it goes? We can also add 19kg in total weight

Comment: Ah my bad, I missed that part. Now consider the latest edited answer. working as expected, just verified myself

Comment: txtV.setText("Total KGs: "+ (weight - weightToDeduct + value.decimalNumber));
Done...

Comment: Awesome, also do vote up... so no one can put the same effort for the same issue

Comment: I vote up pop-up says vote will count 15 reputation.
Thanks alot sir this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm very amazed from your response.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you ! Thank you

Comment: bro when I write in weight editText field 1.42 it will accept 42. How to set condition that cannot accept value greater than 39 in editText field.

Comment: Then we should restrict user to not let the enter value more 2 after decimal by adding InputFilter . So user can enter only a) 1.45 b) 45.80. Then we will round of if decimal value is greater than 40.

Comment: I did it with if condition.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try to divide the weight by 20 :)

Comment: Who voted me down? I want to know why - just because it is a short aswer it doesn't mean that it's not the answer. In this case, it would simplify 20 lines of code into 2.....

Answer (score -1):

Divide by 40:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String s = edW.getText().toString();
    float weight = 40 * Float.parseFloat(s);
    if (weight <= 20) {
        txtV.setText("Total KGs: " + (weight - 1));
    } else {
        int forties = (int) Math.ceil(weight / 40f);
        txtV.setText("Total KGs: " + (weight - (forties * 2)));
    }
}
```

Note: an earlier version of this answer had an off-by-one error when the weight was exactly equal to a multiple of 40.

If you really don't want it to go above 200, you could add this after `float weight` is calculated but before any of the rest of the work is done:

```
if (weight > 200) {
    txtV.setText("Else Running");
    return;
}
```

It then provides identical semantics to your original.

Comment: No. There is no limitation in weight, I wrote 200kg for example.
Let's me clear you:
I have two editText fields one is for mounds and this problem is solved. And other textEdit is for remaining KG along with mounds eg. [4].[19] now 4*40 = 160+19 = 179 total weight.
Deduction 8kg from 160 and 1kg from 19. Now we have 170kg [4].[10] is net weight.

Comment: @ShafiqueRehman Then this should do what you want (without adding the part at the end).

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly let me know what is wrong? This code produces identical results to OP's original in much simpler code, as requested.

Comment: dear I don't down vote you. I don't know who did this.
Thanks for your time my problem was solved.